# Detect packet loss from response of requests.get()

Tags: python, python-requests

is there a way to detect packet loss/incomplete results when performing a `response = requests.get(<URL>)` request? Is this done automatically?

I have thought about comparing `len(response.content)` to `response.headers["content-length"]`, but this seems so trivial that it should already have been included in the library (where I can't find it, at least). This is why I assume that one is set with the other. Side question: Am I correct about this assumption?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that packet loss affects it? I'm literally just guessing here, but I would have thought the packet loss would be handled by hardware/software way before it reaches the library.

Comment: No, I am really not sure and think it's quite possible that this is not the cause of my troubles. But just as a sanity check, I want to rule out this possibility and was wondering if there is a(n easy) way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

So requests does not seem to have this option yet, but the underlying urllib3 does have a flag in its `HTTPResponse` named that is called `enforce_content_length`, which exactly does the check mentioned in the question. It is currently not possible to access this flag via requests, but it is meant to be included in requests 3.0.0 (source: https://github.com/getsentry/responses/issues/394).

With the current version of requests (2.26.0), this can be achieved by patching urllib3 before a `HTTPResponse` is created, e.g. calling a method like this:

```
def patch_urllib3():
    previous_init = urllib3.HTTPResponse.__init__
    def new_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        previous_init(self, *args, enforce_content_length = True, **kwargs)
    urllib3.HTTPResponse.__init__ = new_init
```